# hbm.xml is not generated even though the <table-filter match-name> exists

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I have 3 tables in my DB

- person
- address
- person_address

this is the script sql

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `address` (
  `address_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `address` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`address_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=8 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `person` (
  `person_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`person_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `person_address` (
  `person_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `address_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`person_id`,`address_id`),
  KEY `address_id` (`address_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

ALTER TABLE `person_address`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `person_address_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`address_id`) REFERENCES `address` (`address_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `person_address_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`person_id`) REFERENCES `person` (`person_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

this is the hibernate.reveng.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-reverse-engineering PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Reverse Engineering DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-reverse-engineering-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-reverse-engineering>
  <schema-selection match-catalog="manyToManyTest"/>
  <table-filter match-name="person_address"/>
  <table-filter match-name="address"/>
  <table-filter match-name="person"/>
</hibernate-reverse-engineering>
```

the problem is that when generating pojos and hbm files, the personAddress pojo is not generated (there is no entry `<mapping resource="pojos/PersonAddress.hbm.xml"/>` in hibernate.cfg.xml), why?

Answer (score 0):

PersonAddress class and PersonAddress.hbm.xml should not be generated. Reason is that by default your database maps to two entities: Person and Address and many-to-many relationship between them.

Check does Person.hbm.xml (and inverse in Address.hbm.xml) contain something like:

```
<set ...>
      ...
   <many-to-many class="Address">
</set>
```

If yes, then everything is fine.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's Yes and as you said PersonAddress class and PersonAddress.hbm.xml should not be generated (i just figure that out, it's not the case if you follow this tutorial [link](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/hibernate-webapp.html) which was misleading me the whole time).
The problem is that when executing a HQL query `from Person` (to test the connection) i got the following exception `org.hibernate.MappingException: An association from the table person_address refers to an unmapped class: pojos.Address`